# Pagination with two separate HTML files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, pagination

Can we create a pagination with two separate html files for example i have two file index.html and page2.html.. can we add same pagination into both pages so that index.html links to page2.html when we click on '2' it will redirect us to page2.html..

Comment: You can load a 'fragment' of html. Probably the easiest way to do this is with jQuery. But it can be done perfectly well with vanilla as well.

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap for that.put your page link in anchor tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Pagination</h2>
      <p>The .pagination class provides pagination links:</p>                  
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="index.html.html">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="page4.html">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="page5.html">5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this will not work as a javascript pagination where i have limit of items to be displayed per page and exceeding the limit the last itemon first page will be moved to the 1st position of the 2nd page and so on....

Comment: i am not storing any data in tables as the content is articles with text and images. so i just added the articles into a single file and then i am trying to paginate them using javascript pagination plugin